# counter problem in multiple popup jquery

Tags: jquery, load, popup

I am trying to load an external page as a popup using jquery fadeIn() and fadeOut() functions.

This works fine when I use it to load a specific page in a div, but when I try to generalize the function, some element gets incremented in terms of 2 (i.e.) On first click, there's no problem whereas on second click, the fading in happens twice. Can anyone help me wiht this ??

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
$('a').click(function() {    
var popupid = $(this).attr('rel');    
var url = $(this).attr('id');    
$('#' + popupid).load(url + '.html', function() {    
$('#' + popupid).fadeIn();    
$('body').append('<div id="fade"></div>');    
$('#fade').css({'opacity' : '0.65'}).fadeIn('fast');});    
});    
});    
$('.close').click(function() {    
$('#fade').fadeOut();    
$('popuprel1,popuprel2').fadeOut();    
});    
});
```

I have two divs with id's popuprel1 and popuprel2 where I am loading two external pages.

On giving some alerts, got to know that the clicks is getting incremented by power 2. Please help me how to reset the number of clicks once the function is over.

Comment: Can you post your code..

Comment: Edit your original post and post your code, you'll have better luck in getting some help.

Comment: You bet, glad to help out. Check out the editing tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help  I think you need to put at least 4 spaces before each line of your code to make it formatted properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function() {
```

Maybe this line of code executes multiple times.

Try this:

```
$('a').unbind('click');
$('a').click(function() {
```

But this is just workaround.

Comment: I am trying to access an image element which comes from an external page, like to do some actions with the image once it is called !! It works well with IE but does not work in firefox and chrome..any solutions for this ??